# Permission denied for schema audit

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a database called `uat`, I want the user `documentengine` to be able to connect and operate over it. But I'm stuck with this error:

> Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: permission denied for schema audit

I have tried:

```
grant usage on schema public to documentengine;   
alter default privileges in schema public grant all on tables to documentengine;
alter default privileges in schema public grant all on sequences to documentengine;

grant connect on database uat to documentengine;

grant usage on schema public to documentengine;
grant select on all tables in schema public to documentengine;
grant select on all sequences in schema public to documentengine;


-- grant privileges to documentengine role
grant all privileges on all tables in schema public to documentengine;
```

But still not working.. I wonder what I'm doing wrong here. Any tip ?

**EDIT**

```
uat=> \dn
      List of schemas
      Name       |  Owner   
-----------------+----------
 audit           | postgres
```

Comment: Is there a schema named "audit"?

Comment: Yes, it is. I have updated my question.

Comment: You are using the wrong schema name in your grants: `s/public/audit/g`